# making html in my ts component to create an menu

Tags: angular

I need to create a navBar but I need to do this

```
HTML: string = "<a routerLink="" + router link""</a>"
```

but as standard code in TS, you can't do this because this will close your string

would like some help with this I could post what I got but it is not a beauty and is still needs to be trimmed down.

by the way, I am a starter in Angular/js/ts

Comment: by the way, will probably delete this question because it is a stupid question when I get an answer

Comment: Check my answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello use '' with "" like this

```
HTML: string = "<a routerLink='router link'</a>"
```

Comment: wow forgot that that was stupid about me I need to get a new class of HTML now

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can use it like this.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/xxx/xxx']">
```

Comment: I think Anton answer is better but do you have some documents for this would like to read it.

Comment: Hi you can refer to the official Doc of Angular https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Comment: this looks interesting but I still don't know what it actually does different other than that it doesn't need " " after them but I could use ' ' instead and I don't know how much it would help me with my current project so gone keep it with stuff I know and I thought the official doc might help but it didn't.

Comment: hi Marc, sure brackets in [routerLink] is been used for the property binding. whereas " " after that is the angular syntax (whatever to be binded with the property.). Inside that the squre bracket and string is the format in which route is to be given.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax with **\"** :

```
let HTML: string = "<a routeLink=\"['/my/link']\">link you want</a>";
```